# Javascript executed after the load of a PartialView via ajax in a JQuery Dialog works only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I know it's a long title ^^

I'm using MVC 4 and JQuery version 1.8.2.

I'm loading a PartialView in a JQuery Dialog and everything works fine.

Recently i wanted to add some Javascript, to hide a textbox in the Dialog, and here starts my pain.

The Javascript hide code works :

- Only once, if i close the dialog with     $(this).dialog('close');
- Everytime, if i close the dialog with     $(this).remove();

I'm not an expert in JQuery / Javascript but i'd like to understand what's going on :)

Here's my code :

```
$(function dialogLink() {

// Don't allow browser caching of forms
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

// Wire up the click event of any current or future dialog links
$('.dialogLink').on('click', function () {
    var element = $(this);

    // Retrieve values from the HTML5 data attributes of the link       
    var dialogTitle = element.attr('data-dialog-title');
    var updateTargetId = '#' + element.attr('data-update-target-id');
    var updateUrl = element.attr('data-update-url');

    // Generate a unique id for the dialog div
    var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";

    // Load the form into the dialog div
    $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {        

        $(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            title: dialogTitle,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    // Manually submit the form                       
                    var form = $('form', this);
                    $(form).submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
                //"Cancel": function () { $(this).remove(); }
            }
        });

        // Enable client side validation
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this);

        // Setup the ajax submit logic
        wireUpForm(this, updateTargetId, updateUrl);


        // Working only once code
        $('#PossibleAnswerContainer').hide();

        $('#StatisticDataType').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).val() === 'List') {
                $('#PossibleAnswerContainer').show();
            } else {
                $('#PossibleAnswerContainer').hide();
            }
        });

    });
    return false;
});
});

function wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {

    // Do not submit if the form
    // does not pass client side validation
    if (!$(this).valid())
        return false;

    // Client side validation passed, submit the form
    // using the jQuery.ajax form
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            // Check whether the post was successful
            if (result.Success) {
                // Close the dialog
                $(dialog).dialog('close');

                // Reload the updated data in the target div
                $(updateTargetId).load(updateUrl);

            } else {
                // Reload the dialog to show model errors                   
                $(dialog).html(result);

                // Enable client side validation
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(dialog);

                // Setup the ajax submit logic
                wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i ended up with this :

```
$(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                height: 'auto',             
                width: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                title: dialogTitle,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        // Manually submit the form                       
                        var form = $('form', this);
                        $(form).submit();
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }      
                },
                close: function () { $(this).remove(); } 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Wire up the click event of any current or future dialog links
$('.dialogLink').on('click'
```

That statement is incorrect. `on()` does not work like `.live()` being that once you attach `.live()` it will detect dynamically added elements.

It should be.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dialogLink'), function(){
```

to attach future event handlers to static elements named, `.dialogLink`.

Also, replace `$(document)`, with the closest static parent element, such as `$('#container')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to set up what you are proposing. $('#Foo').on('click', '.dialogLink'), function() { //Do things } In my view, i added <div id="Foo"> which containing the link with the Css Class .dialogLink. When i click on the link i have the JS error : Object does not support the property or method "apply". Any ideas ?

Comment: `('click', '.dialogLink'),` there should not be a closing parenthesis after `'.dialogLink'`

Comment: Okay, my .on is correct and working now.
But i still have the issue with the // Working only once code part :/